Converting pine script barssince function to python trading bot
I have a strategy in trading view I am converting to a python bot. In the strategy, when all the signals are "On" only one trade is to be opened per supertrend direction, the strategy only looks for new signals once the supertrend changes direction. On pine script I achieved this by using the barssince function and comparing when there was the last buy/sell order vs the long/short supertrend.
//Plot once per supertrend
isUptrend = direction < 0
isDowntrend = direction > 0
barsSinceSwitch = ta.barssince(direction != direction[1])
barsSinceLong = ta.barssince(isDowntrend)
barsSinceShort = ta.barssince(isUptren
buyCount = ta.barssince(long)
sellCount = ta.barssince(short)

if (buyCount[1] > barsSinceLong[1])
    inBuyTrend := true
else
    inBuyTrend := false

if (sellCount[1] > barsSinceShort[1])
    inShortTrend := true
else
    inShortTrend := false

How can I implement this in python?
I have tried to track the change of the supertrend direction
